# Query related Tasks does not work

Tags: apex, soql, map, tasks, taskrelation

I need to query all related tasks from a contact (currentRecordId) but my code below shows nothing.
What I'm doing wrong?

```
Map<Id, TaskRelation> relatedTasks1 = new Map<Id, TaskRelation>([select taskId from TaskRelation where relationId = :currentRecordId]); 
system.debug('size relatedtasks1 ' +relatedtasks1.size()); // 3 items
List<Task> listtasks = [select Id, Subject, CreatedDate, Createdby.Name, Owner.Name, RecordType.Name, Status, Who.Name, Who.Id, What.Name from Task where Id IN :relatedTasks1.keySet()];
system.debug('size listtasks ' +listtasks.size()); // 0 items
for(Task a : listtasks) { 
    wrapperList.add(new Wrapper(a, 'Task'));
}
```

DEBUG of map relatedtasks1

> 09:36:49:197 VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT
> [23]|relatedTasks1|{"0RT1x0000094HFHGA2":{"TaskId":"00T1x00000CSmgFEAT","Id":"0RT1x0000094HFHGA2"},"0RT1x0000094HEeGAM":{"TaskId":"00T1x00000CSmdSEAT","Id":"0RT1x0000094HEeGAM"},"0RT1x0000094HF8GAM":{"TaskId":"00T1x00000CSmgAEAT","Id":"0RT1x0000094HF8GAM"}}|0x3964be86

Debug of list `Listtasks`

> 09:36:49:199 SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN [24]|Aggregations:0|SELECT Id,
> Subject, CreatedDate, Createdby.Name, Owner.Name, RecordType.Name,
> Status, Who.Name, Who.Id, What.Name FROM Task WHERE Id = :tmpVar1
> 09:36:49:206 SOQL_EXECUTE_EXPLAIN [24]|Index on Task : [Id], cardinality: 3, sobjectCardinality: 29, relativeCost 0.333

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is with `Map<Id, TaskRelation> relatedTasks1 = new Map<Id, TaskRelation>([select taskId from TaskRelation where relationId = :currentRecordId]);`

when you are passing into the constructor of the `Map` a list of sobjects, the key is set to record id. In this example, it is `TaskRelation.Id`

In the next line `List<Task> listtasks = [select Id, Subject, CreatedDate, Createdby.Name, Owner.Name, RecordType.Name, Status, Who.Name, Who.Id, What.Name from Task where Id IN :relatedTasks1.keySet()];` `Task` records are filtered by `Task.Id`, but key set returns `TaskRelation.Id` set. So even not proper sobject ids are used. Sрould be ids of `Task`, but сгккутедн ids of `TaskRelation`.

There is one step that is missing. Getting from `relatedTasks1` `TaskId` field values.
Your code should look like this:

```
Map<Id, TaskRelation> relatedTasks1 = new Map<Id, TaskRelation>([select taskId from TaskRelation where relationId = :currentRecordId]);

Set<Id> taskIdsSet = new Set<Id>();
for(TaskRelation relation: relatedTasks1.values()){
    taskIdsSet.add(relation.TaskId);
}


List<Task> listtasks = [select Id, Subject, CreatedDate, Createdby.Name, Owner.Name, RecordType.Name, Status, Who.Name, Who.Id, What.Name from Task where Id IN :taskIdsSet];
```

---

Moreover, it is possible to do it in one query using a nested query:

```
List<Task> tasks= [
    SELECT Id, Subject
    FROM Task
    WHERE Id IN (
        SELECT TaskId
        FROM TaskRelation
        where RelationId = :currentRecordId
    )
];
```

---

Or you can query needed info also using a parent relationship:

```
List<TaskRelation> relations= [
    SELECT Id, Task.Subject, Task.Owner.Name
    FROM TaskRelation
    WHERE RelationId = :currentRecordId
];
```